# reserve word field name table alias query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax-error

I have a table 'x' with field 'value'. I can query this field if I enclose it in brackets. Such as:

```
select x.[value] from x
```

problem is I need to do a multiple part join where this table is aliased.

When I alias the table as follows:

```
select foo.[value] from x as 'foo'
```

This breaks with:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'foo'.... 1 statement(s) executed
```

It would be awesome if whoever built this table hadn't used a reserved word but I am not so lucky! Any thoughts on syntax that might work here?

"value" is a VARCHAR(100) if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [] instead of '

```
select foo.[value] from x as [foo]
```

Or just write

```
select foo.[value] from x as foo
```

Comment: Funny, I got it right before you posted. Happy to give you the check. Thanks